# Use Search box for AutoCompleteBox in LightSwitch

Tags: c#, search, autocompletebox, lightswitch-2012

I want to use LightSwitch Search Data Screen for display my tables value and use the search box for find some value from my tables.
My first table is "TBCompany", and the second table is "TBNode". I also have a table "TBNodeCompanies" that contains "TBCompany" and "TBNodes"'s Ids that related to each other. I add "TBCompany" and "TBNodeCompanies" to my Search Screen. you can see my LightSwitch Designer in below image:

[image: LightSwitch Designer]

When I use search box in first table, "TBCompany", It works fine, but in the second table, "TBNodeCompanies", that contains **AutoCompleteBox** the search box is not working! How can I enable search box on this screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In this link It's completely explained.

[How to Create a Search Screen that Can Search Properties of Related Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/07/13/how-to-create-a-search-screen-that-can-search-properties-of-related-entities-john-chen.aspx/)